# When time zones are different is a pandas dataframe, how to change time zone?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime, timezone

I got a dataframe like this:

```
   State   Timezone    UTC_Time               Parking
0  OH      US/Eastern  2019-01-01 12:00:00    12
1  OH      US/Eastern  2019-01-01 13:00:00    11
2  WI      US/Central  2019-01-01 12:00:00    65
3  WI      US/Central  2019-01-01 13:00:00    67
```

I want to add a column 'Local_Time' by dt.tz_convert('XXX') where that 'XXX' is what in column Timezone.

Previously when there was only Ohio data I counld simply use

```
df['Local_Time'] = df['UTC_Time'].dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

I tried

```
df['Local_Time'] = df['UTC_Time'].dt.tz_convert(df['Timezone'])
```

but failed with ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. I suppose there are other numpy manipulations behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this (almost) because `pd.DatetimeIndex` supports only one timezone but you can have multiple instance of `pd.Timestamp` inside a `Series`. What you lost here is the `dt` accessor because your dtype column will be `object` instead of `datetime64`.

```
df['Local_Time'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['UTC_Time'].tz_localize(x['Timezone']), axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  State    Timezone             UTC_Time  Parking                 Local_Time
0    OH  US/Eastern  2019-01-01 12:00:00       12  2019-01-01 12:00:00-05:00
1    OH  US/Eastern  2019-01-01 13:00:00       11  2019-01-01 13:00:00-05:00
2    WI  US/Central  2019-01-01 12:00:00       65  2019-01-01 12:00:00-06:00
3    WI  US/Central  2019-01-01 13:00:00       67  2019-01-01 13:00:00-06:00
```

Check dtype:

```
>>> df.dtypes
State                 object
Timezone              object
UTC_Time      datetime64[ns]
Parking                int64
Local_Time            object
dtype: object
```

You have to know, it's totally sub optimal to have multiple timezone into a same Series, mainly because you lose the `dt` accessor so you have to access value individually and not in a vectorized way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I went to the fact sheet of pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert but still didn't get it. Just a rough guess that this might be because of the mechanics of the function itself. Here your explanation is very useful!

Comment: `tz_convert` transforms a DatetimeIndex with an origin timezone to an another timezone and only one. In the other hand `tz_localize` convert a naive DatetimeIndex (with no indication of tz) to a local datetime: it does not change the value of datetime, just append the timezone to the date.

Comment:  Oh this adds more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`.dt.tz_convert` only works with one timezone passed, so you'll have to do this row-by-row. However, a more efficient way than that would be to group by `Timezone` and call `tz_convert` for each group on all the `UTC_Time` values for that group:

```
df['Local_Time'] = df.groupby('Timezone', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g['UTC_Time'].dt.tz_convert(g['Timezone'].iloc[0])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  State    Timezone                  UTC_Time  Parking                 Local_Time
0    OH  US/Eastern 2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00       12  2019-01-01 06:00:00-06:00
1    OH  US/Eastern 2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00       11  2019-01-01 07:00:00-06:00
2    WI  US/Central 2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00       65  2019-01-01 07:00:00-05:00
3    WI  US/Central 2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00       67  2019-01-01 08:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: HI @richardec. What is the output of `df['Local_Time].dtype` please?

Comment: Hmmm, @Corralien `df['Local_Time'].dtype` is `dtype('O')`, but `df['UTC_Time'].dtype` is `datetime64[ns, UTC]`

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So you lost the `dt` accessor. Check my answer :) It's not a solvable problem. That's why UTC exist. lol.

Comment: Hmmm, and `df['Local_Time'].astype(df['UTC_Time'].dtype)` doesn't work: `ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! BTW there will always be a lot of unclears when it comes to pandas datetime .

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, I understand. Pandas has lots of tricky parts :) @Elaine have you tried my answer? It's probably faster than the accepted answer by virtue of the fact that there are much fewer calls to `tz_convert`... :)